# {"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."} in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting  `{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}` error while trying to post a change password API. I'm using postman and please let me know if any more details are needed in the comment section. Thanks in advance.

Serializers.py

```
class PasswordChangeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Views.py

```
class PasswordChange(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = PasswordChangeSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = request.user

            password = serializer.data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            content = {'success': _('Password changed.')}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: is ```X-CSRFToken``` is set in the request header?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm seeing this for the first time. I'm new to REST

Comment: Please post some of the authenticaiton-related information from your settings.py, and possibly what the postman request settings are.

Comment: Please include in the queston the keys starting with `CSRF_` present in your settings.py.